# alias disables colour sustainably in bash

Tags: bash, centos, fedora, alias

When I do

```
tree -N
```

I get nice coloured output. When I then

```
alias tree="tree -N"
tree
```

output is black & white. When I then

```
unalias tree
tree -N
```

output is still black & white!

GNU bash, version 4.3.39(1), tree v1.7.0

That happens on Fedora 22 and CentOS 7

NOT on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Ironic comments aren't going to help you much. Have a nice day.

Comment: It's just been a case of blindness. I *sustainably* overlooked an `alias tree='tree -C'` in my `~/.bash_aliases`. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there was an alias for "tree" before you added your own alias.  Referring to the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tree), it has an option that might be useful in an alias:

> **`-C`**
>
> Turn colorization on always, using built-in color defaults if the **`LS_COLORS`** environment variable is not set. Useful to colorize output to a pipe.

That could have been used to "help" with cases where the user's environment lacked the **`LS_COLORS`** environment variable.  Removing all aliases would (in that case) get the no-color behavior.

I do not see a predefined alias under `/etc` in my Fedora 21, but customizations of this type are common with Red Hat.